# Cloud ML Feature methods

Tags: google-cloud-ml

The pre-processing page in the cloud ML How to guide (https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/preprocessing-data) says that you should see the SDK reference documentation for details about each type of feature and the

Can anyone point me to this documentation or a list of feature types and their methods? I'm trying to setup a discrete target but keep getting "data type int64 expected type: float" errors whenever I set my target to .discrete() rather than .continuous()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the SDK reference documentation:

1. Navigate to the directory where you want to install the docs in the
   command line. If you used `~/google-cloud-ml` to download the samples
   as recommended in the setup guide, it's a good place.
2. Copy the documentation archive to your chosen directory using
   `gsutil`:

   ```
   gsutil cp gs://cloud-ml/sdk/cloudml-docs.latest.tar.gz .
   ```
3. Unpack the archive:

   ```
   tar -xf cloudml-docs.latest.tar.gz
   ```

This creates a `docs` directory inside the directory that you chose. The
documentation is essentially a local website: open `docs/index.html` in your browser to open it at its root. You can find the transform references in there.

(This information is now in the [setup guide](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/getting-set-up#setting_up_your_environment) as well. It's the final step under **LOCAL: MAC/LINUX**)

Comment: Thanks, I was running through the tutorials in Cloud Datalab rather than setting up a local environment so didn't see those instructions.

Answer (score 0):

On the type-related errors, let's assume for a bit that your feature set is specified somewhat along the following lines:

```
feature_set = {
    'target': features.target('category').discrete()
}
```

When a discrete target is specified like above, the data-type of the target feature is an int64 due to one of the following:

1. No vocab for target data-column (i.e. 'category') was generated during the analysis of your data, i.e. the metadata (in the generated metadata.yaml) has an empty list for the target data-column's vocab.
2. A vocab for 'category' was indeed generated, and the data-type of the very first item (or key) of this vocab was an int.

Under these circumstances, if a float is encountered, the transformation to the target feature's data-type will fail.

Instead, casting the entire data-column ('category' in this case) into a float should help with this.