# Cloud ML Python SDK Documentation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

The google cloud docs make reference to Python SDK Documentation in a few places.

Ex.
*feature_type*: The method that creates the type of feature object you want, such as key, target, or text. **Refer to the Cloud ML Python SDK for descriptions of all supported feature types.**
https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/concepts/preprocessing-overview

For the life of me, I can't find this SDK Documentation anywhere? Is it currently published?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find an answer on stackoverflow. It doesn't seem to be documented on googles website anywhere:

---

You need to download the SDK reference documentation:

Navigate to the directory where you want to install the docs in the
command line. If you used ~/google-cloud-ml to download the samples as recommended in the setup guide, it's a good place.

1. Copy the documentation archive to your chosen directory using gsutil:

   gsutil cp gs://cloud-ml/sdk/cloudml-docs.latest.tar.gz .
2. Unpack the archive:

   tar -xf cloudml-docs.latest.tar.gz
3. This creates a docs directory inside the directory that you chose. The documentation is essentially a local website: open docs/index.html in your browser to open it at its root. You can find the transform references in there.

(This information is now in the setup guide as well. It's the final step under LOCAL: MAC/LINUX)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40519472/6283150